Security Implications of listen_tls = 1 and tls_auth = 0 in libvirtd.conf
I've been auditing the configuration of libvirtd.conf on a cloud platform's host machine and have encountered a configuration that I'm unsure about. The settings in question are:
listen_tls = 1 tls_auth = 0
With listen_tls enabled, but tls_auth set to 0, I am concerned about the potential security implications of this configuration. Can someone explain whether this setup could pose a security risk? Specifically, I would like to understand if the lack of TLS authentication (tls_auth = 0) compromises the security even though TLS listening is enabled.
Thank you for your insights!
